# like open graph object from native android like button FB SDK V 4

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to implement Facebook [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) using [LikeView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LikeView/) in my Android app. I have integrated SDK4 with the app.

I want to like a photo published by my friend.

This is my code

```
LikeView likeView = new LikeView(this);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType("123456789", LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
```

The first parameter is Facebook Open Graph object id for a photo.
The error response is :

> error={"error_code":10,"error":"server_error","error_description":"Error
>   connecting to Facebook servers. Please try again
>   later.","error_reason":"server_error"}

If I just replace the second line of code with this, it is working well.

```
likeView.setObjectIdAndType("https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers", LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

Documentation says that the first parameter i.e. object ID for the Like button can be a URL or a Facebook ID. Please suggest.

**Update**

I filed a bug report for this. And this is the response from Facebook.

> Sorry to say that like view cannot be used to like photos. It is
>   designed to like page/open graph type only. I suggest that you use
>   graph api to like the photo.

Comment: What id are you using?

Comment: I am using Facebook Id of the photo. The ID is correct and I am able to load it in Graph API Explorer.

Comment: So why are you using LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH?

Comment: because its a open graph object id. should I remove this or try something else? Other values may be DEFAULT, UNKNOWN or PAGE.

Comment: You just said it is a photo id.

Comment: are they different? I found the ID in URL parameter of the photo. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=123456789
and I can query the same ID in Graph API explorer like v2.3/123456789

Comment: I'm pretty sure the like button don't work for photos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74952/discussion-between-sandeep-kumar-and-wizkid).

Comment: Right, you can't like a FB photo via LikeView, it only works for OG objects; which the URL is, or a Facebook page.

Comment: @WizKid Emil, Do we some way to confirm this? Because the error what I am receiving is totally misleading.

Comment: File a bug for the error. But like buttons have never worked for photos